# What is a Vain Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sup>This is inspired by the What is a Word/Phrase™ puzzles originally created by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee).</sup>

If a word has a certain property, I call it a Vain Word™.

In each of the short, unrelated sentences below, only one of the choices is a Vain Word™.

The sentences are for context only, and do not affect whether a word is a Vain Word™.

> 1. I missed the bus, so I took a ( **CAB** / **TAXI** ) to work.
> 2. The old house down the street is covered in ( **IVY** / **VINES** ).
> 3. Having too much to drink can make you ( **VOMIT** / **PUKE** ).
> 4. To my dismay, a ( **YOUNGSTER** / **YOUTH**  ) always loiters in front of my store.
> 5. Archaeologists who explore tombs may have to contend with a (  **ZOMBIE** / **MUMMY** ).
> 6. I noticed the ocean was very ( **WAVY** / **CALM** ) while I was sitting on the beach today.
> 7. Having been beaten by my enemy last time, this time I was prepared to ( **OUTSMART** / **OUTWIT** ) him.
> 8. The controversial social experiment turned out to be a ( **HOAX** / **SHAM** ).
> 9. The mathematician was stuck trying to prove something, until he recalled a rather obscure ( **AXIOM** / **THEOREM** ).
> 10. My friend showed my his ( **GARGANTUAN** / **MAMMOTH** ) truck. It was quite an eyesore.

**What makes a word a Vain Word™?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vain words are

> made up of letters which are symmetrical about the Y-axis, presumably because they like to look at themselves in the mirror

That is:

> 1. TAXI
>  2. IVY
>  3. VOMIT
>  4. YOUTH
>  5. MUMMY
>  6. WAVY
>  7. OUTWIT
>  8. HOAX
>  9. AXIOM
>  10. MAMMOTH

Comment: was this question too easy...coz that was fast..

Comment: @manshu: I'm wondering that myself :P Good job question_asker.